# Return a promise without making an angular $http call?

Tags: angularjs, http, promise

How do you return a promise without making an http call? ATM I have some mock JSON that will get replaced by an API call.

Comment: return $q.when(json);

Comment: @Stewie thanks but is this ok as my true upstream caller will be expecting the same json result as a $http.get(

Comment: $http service returns response object, with `data` property holding the actual json, so you just need to wrap your json in simple object: `$q.when({data:<json>})`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a full example. Notice we use $q to get the deferral, do something interesting, then use the "resolve" to send the final. I'm using JSON just like $http would, and using the JSON filter to display it.

Code:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.service("myService", function($q, $timeout) {
    return {
        getData: function() {
            var deferral = $q.defer(); 
            $timeout(function() {
            deferral.resolve({ 
                id: 1, 
                status: "Returned from service.", 
                promiseComplete: true });
            }, 2000);
            return deferral.promise;
        }
    };
});
app.controller("myController", function($scope, myService) {
    var result = { status: "Initialized." };
    $scope.result = result; 
    myService.getData().then(function(data) { $scope.result = data; });
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jeremylikness/HL7h2/

When you run it, you will see one JSON item in the output, then about 2 seconds later it will update to the result of the service call.

Answer (score 1):

This should probably be a comment but I see this very often and think it is bad practice especially regarding principles like DRY and KISS.

`$timeout()` will return a promise. You don't need to craft one yourself. This means for mocking a `$http` request you can simply write something like:

```
var promise = $timeout(function () {
    return {
        data: // some data
    }
});
promise.then(function (response) {
    // do whatever you like
});
```

Here is a modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1vgs7nbj/1/ (I stole most of it from Jeremy Likness's Answer above).

IMHO, this is the best way to do this as it is clean and probably the shortest approach.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
return $q.defer().promise
```

you can do

```
var promise = $q.defer().promise;
promise.then(success,error)
return promise;
```

Comment: sorry, why the 2 approaches here?

Comment: first one is just returning a promise as you asked, second one is also for defining callbacks on the promise